# Gaining access to wordpress core functions in my plugin's custom script

Tags: php, ajax, apache, wordpress

I have created a WordPress plugin where there are 2 php files `a.php` and `b.php`. `a.php` is the main plugin file where as `b.php` will be called using AJAX. Now inside `b.php`, I need to access WordPress core functionality like `plugins_url`, `sanitize_text_field` etc. Previously, I had included the `wp-load.php` file using `require_once`, but that is rejected by WordPress.

Any better way to achieve this?

Comment: are you calling ajax using in WordPress way ?

Comment: Nope, I just used jQuery.ajax.

Comment: you may need to change your ajax according to wordpress way. so it won't be rejected

Comment: `include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-blog-header.php'; header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");` try this also on top of your `b.php` file and use `WP`'s functions , may it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save yourself time and just do ajax WP way.

First, add your script and pass ajax url to it (you can hardcode it if your plugin is for personal use) like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my_ajax_script', plugins_url( '/myscript.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
wp_localize_script( 'my_ajax_script', 'my_ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php'));
```

In js, you can access url via `my_ajax_object.ajax_url`

Your ajax call would look like

```
var request = {action: 'name_of_your_action' /*other params go here*/}
$.ajax({type: "post", dataType: "json", url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url, data: request}).done(function (e) 
{
    alert('All cool');
})
```

Then write function to handle your ajax call

```
function my_ajax_handler()
{
    /*Do some magic*/
    echo json_encode(array('some_response_var'=>'some response value'));
    die();
}
```

Lastly, let wordpress know that you want call with action `name_of_your_action` to be handled by your function. You can do it like this

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_name_of_your_action', 'my_ajax_handler' ); // for logged in users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_name_of_your_action', 'my_ajax_handler'); // for guests
```

Please refer to [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

In order to transform regular PHP pages into ones that utilize WordPress, you need to add either of the following code snippets to the start of each page.

```
<?php 
/* Short and sweet */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website#Grab_the_header